# Get if player is at certain location, then set scoreboard (1.15)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make a parkour map with checkpoints that set depending on stage number. In theory, this command in a repeating command block;

```
execute as @a at @s if entity @s positioned as @s[x=-17,y=6,z=-2] run scoreboard players set @s stage 2
```

...should work, but it's completely ignoring `if entity @s positioned` and simply setting `stage` to 2. I've attempted just doing `...positioned -17 6 -2` but that has the same outcome.

Am I missing something important, or is Minecraft being weird? If I am correct, it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if entity @s` checks if the entity that is yourself exists, which is (almost) always true.

`positioned` executes a command at another position.

In general, looking at the wiki helps, it would have told you that `/execute positioned` is a completely separate branch of `/execute`.

What you want is `positioned <coordinates> if entity @s[distance=..1]` (or any other radius). This checks at that position if there's this entity in a radius of 1. And you don't even need `at @s`.

Comment: So, basically, it works in reverse order, checks for position and *then* for an entity. Huh. Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing is reversed, your initial command just used two completely separate parts of `/execute` as if they were one, but they aren't.

Comment: Thanks, @EarthToAccess, you just gave me the final few points for the golden [tag:minecraft] tag badge, something only 4 people have!